# PHP adding child and attributes on existing XML file

Tags: php, xml, attributes, simplexml

I've been reading about SimpleXML and some other stuff but I have a problem I can't figure out.

So I have this simple almost empty XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData> 
</imageData>
```

What I want to do is every time I click a button, the XML document opens and appends a new child so it will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData>
   <image id="myID"> <--- (Note the attribute in here)
      <person>MyPersonName</person>
      <number>MyNumber</number>
   </image> 
</imageData>
```

So far, I've been able to make it work a bit using something like this, yet I can't seem to find a way to append an attribute to the image tag which I need to be able to insert different child 'images' tags based on the ID attribute, as I'm getting very confused on how to use the `$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($imageData);` function on an external XML document:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('myXML.xml');
$xml->addChild('image'); <--Want to add an id="myID" attribute to this child
$xml->image->addChild('person', 'myPersonName'); <--Want to add this child to the image tag with the attribute I added up there)
$xml->image->addChild('number','Mynumber');
file_put_contents('myXML.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SimpleXMLElement::addChild()](http://docs.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) returns the newly created element as another SimpleXMLElement instance you can work on

```
<?php
$imageData = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><imageData />');

onClick( $imageData ); echo $imageData->asXML(); echo "\r\n----\r\n";
onClick( $imageData ); echo $imageData->asXML(); echo "\r\n----\r\n";
onClick( $imageData ); echo $imageData->asXML(); echo "\r\n----\r\n";
onClick( $imageData ); echo $imageData->asXML(); echo "\r\n----\r\n";


function onClick($imageData) {
    static $id = 0;
    $img = $imageData->addChild('image');
    $img['id'] = ++$id;
    $img->person = 'person #'.$id;
    $img->number = '47'.$id;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData><image id="1"><person>person #1</person><number>471</number></image></imageData>

----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData><image id="1"><person>person #1</person><number>471</number></image><image id="2"><person>person #2</person><number>472</number></image></imageData>

----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData><image id="1"><person>person #1</person><number>471</number></image><image id="2"><person>person #2</person><number>472</number></image><image id="3"><person>person #3</person><number>473</number></image></imageData>

----
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<imageData><image id="1"><person>person #1</person><number>471</number></image><image id="2"><person>person #2</person><number>472</number></image><image id="3"><person>person #3</person><number>473</number></image><image id="4"><person>person #4</person><number>474</number></image></imageData>

----
```

Comment: This actually answers my question except for the part that I still don't know how to call my XML file to add a new child to the imageData tag, as in, I have an XML in "C://Users/user/Desktop/directory" and I want to be able to open it and add my data there.

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php | and once the file is read you just do what onClick() does. But how to avoid [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use new SimpleXMLElement syntax. Just do

```
$xml->image->addAttribute('id', 'myID');
```

Comment: I tried that but it throws `Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::addAtribute()`

Comment: Attribute - with two `t`s. But the code as it is will always work on the first `<image>` element - not what you want as far as I understood the question.